# How to repeat a array a certain amount of times

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a number of days which is equal 10 and I have a array of week days "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Firday". Now I want to repeat this array 10 times. For example if days = 9 then the array will print out "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Firday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"

This is the code I've already tried

```
$days = 9;
$arr = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Firday");
foreach (range(1, $days) as $i) {
 foreach ($arr as $value) {
   echo $value . ', ';
 }

}
```

The result I got back was

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday, 
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Firday,
```

But the result I was expecting was

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, 
Thursday, Firday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `for` loop and the modulus operator `%` to ensure your index doesn't exceed the range of the array:

```
$days = 9;
$arr = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i % 5] . ',';
}
```

Output:

```
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,
```

If you don't want the trailing comma, just add a test for the end of the loop before outputting it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i % 5] . ($i == $days - 1 ? '' : ',');
}
```

Output:

```
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CUqiG)

Comment: is their a way I could loop through the array of days instead of echoing it

Comment: @fuzzybuddy sure, just change the `echo ...` to `$day = $arr[$i % 5];` then you can do what you like with the `$day` variable

Answer (score 1):

You were iterating an array `$days` times. You should iterating through the array `$days` indexes.

```
$days = 13;
$arr = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
foreach (range(0, $days - 1) as $i) {
    echo $arr[$i % 5] . ',';
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Cloud Soh Jun Fu but there is a slight problem when I set the number of days more than 10 it gives me a error saying Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in